# measure time in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, time

I have a function(A) and somewhere in that function, another function(B) gets called, what I need to do is measure how long will the execution of function B takes and return it on function A. It is python 2.7 version project, Id appreciate more simple explained answers :3

```
def A(B):
 #stuff happens here
 #time_before_execution
 B()
 #time_after_execution
 #return how long the execution took in seconds
```

Comment: p.s. the project is already using import time, so if there is a way using that library, id choose it over something else :x

Answer (score 1):

```
def A(B):
#stuff happens here
    start = time.time()
    B()
    end = time.time()
    return (end-start)
```